# How to load add-in for a company

Tags: excel, ms-office, add-in, office-addins, excel-addins

Our company has deployed excel online but when open office add-in, it shows

[image]

This tip is too simple, I don't understand what should I do next.

> 请从信任中心添加或启用加载项目录 => Please add or enable add-in directory from the trust center.

What is the trust center? I can't find it on Excel Online.

Comment: Please add more details. What is the add-in? Is it one that your company has created or one that you obtained from AppSource? What steps lead to the error?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to deploy within your company you can create a shared folder and ask your users to load addin from `Shared Folder`. Please follow @Rick Kirkham advise and the link
2. Depends on the office version and windows build version addin may use IE or Edge browser to load. Then you have to strictly follow @Eugene Astafiev advise and give a try.

I believe in your manifest file you have declared the App domain and the value properly where your addin is serving from. For Example

```
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://youraddinlocation.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
```

**Note: Add more appdomain entry depends on how Addins fetching data**

Then to deploy within a company

1. https://admin.microsoft.com/
2. Click Settings> Services and Addins > Deploy Addin

[image]

3. Then choose> upload a custom app

[image]

4. Then upload the manifest file to test it locally

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, end users or administrators can add the domain of the add-in to the list of trusted sites in Internet Explorer. Use the same procedure whether you're using the Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge browser. Do not add the URL for an add-in to your list of trusted sites if you don't trust the add-in.

To add a URL to your list of trusted sites:

1. In Internet Explorer, choose the Tools button, and go to Internet options > Security.
2. Select the Trusted sites zone, and choose Sites.
3. Enter the URL that appears in the error message, and choose Add.
4. Try to use the add-in again. If the problem persists, verify the settings for the other security zones and ensure that the add-in domain is in the same zone as the URL that is displayed in the address bar of the Office application.
5. This issue occurs when the Dialog API is used in pop-up mode. To prevent this issue from occurring, use the displayInFrame flag. This requires that your page support display within an iframe. The following example shows how to use the flag.

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(startAddress, {displayInFrame:true}, callback);
```

See [Troubleshoot user errors with Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/testing-and-troubleshooting) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Office has a Trust Center that you can get to in Excel by going to **File** | **Options** | **Trust Center**.

The error may be telling you that you need to create a trusted place for deploying the manifest of the add-in. For details about how to do this, see [Sideload Office Add-ins for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins).